# When to use structured record/object, when to use list of strings?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I've written some apps using simple imperative way - now I want to learn more about building software the object oriented way.

My goal is to take an Excel file and load one of the tables into memory. I can do this by:

1. Creating a list of strings for each row, and store the table in
   list
2. Creating a structure/ class for the records, and store the table in list of objects

The simplest is of course first solution, but I want to know the advantages of second - most importantly which one is better and when?

From my perspective creating an struct/object for each record, and then using fields/properties to get the values makes the program unnecessarily complicated (if I plan to load the table to database even more). For some reason though this was one of the proposed solution this question:
[Are 2 dimensional Lists possible in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665299/are-2-dimensional-lists-possible-in-c).

Comment: You can refer this rule: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: I assume this is a C# question?

Comment: @CodesInChaos maybe, I don't know how much other languages differ. I mean it in general, when developing something using OOP

Comment: In C++ the difference is only the default visibility of members. Java doesn't support user-defined structs at all. C#/VB.NET and Delphi are pretty similar in that regard.

Comment: When developing something using OOP, you should use objects, because if you don't use objects, you are not developing something using OOP. However, e.g. in C♯, VB.NET, C++, instances of structs *are* objects, so for those particular languages, your question doesn't make sense, because if you are using structs, you *are* using objects.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That reasoning feels rather backwards. Write good code, which might happen to be OOP (or not, if it doesn't fit the usecase). Also you don't need class inheritance to be OOP.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: where did I say anything about class inheritance? Or classes, or inheritance, for that matter? I probably should have said "messages" instead of objects, though.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I responded to an earlier version of the comment which only had the first sentence.

Comment: @JörgWMittag so the question is - should I create separate class or just define the struct in such case? that is quite well explained in article linked above by DongWei.
now what bothers me is what you gain when you have a row stored in such object rather than in simple two-dimensional list

Comment: See my edit, I tried to solve the misunderstanding, the question has nothing to do with the difference between structs and classes in C# or C++, this just distracts from what you really want to know.

Comment: just make sure to have absolutely clear what you are doing. In delphi I've run into the struct/object hell where one is passed by value and the other by reference. It made one big mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about one two-dimensional table in an Excel sheet, where each column has a certain meaning, not a full excel document with all possible meta information.

If you know the specific columns and their meaning beforehand, at compile time,  (typically the columns have headers with some header titles), then using a class or struct with specific fields is in most cases the better approach. That way, you make the column structure explicit in your program's code, each time you access a value from a certain column you access a named field, which makes it much more understable what your program is doing right there. Additionally, your program becomes more type safe, which means less error-prone.

However, if you are going to write a program which deals with arbitrarily structured tables, where the columns and headers and the meaning of the columns is not known at compile time, then you need a more generic data structure like a two-dimensional list of strings.